# What To Do With SVG Native Styles When Converting To Symbol

Tags: html, css, svg

I have the following use case: some client provided me with a large SVG, presumably exported from Figma, with a style tag at top.  Since I want to animate certain fragments, I can't use an `<img>` tag, since the SVG is so large, I don't want to inline it, so I split it up in `<symbol>` elements which I then link via `<use>` in a small inline SVG in my React app (but could be any website I guess).

The problem is that I haven't found a way to make the styles work.  I put them in the inline SVG, but apparently styles can't cross document boundaries, which makes sense.  Yet also leaving them in the original SVG doesn't seem to work.  Neither does putting them inside `<symbol>` or a `<defs>` tag.

Note that I don't want to use any CSS or customize the SVG appearance, I just want it to look as provided.

Is there any way to get this working or do I have to run some script which inlines all styles?

Comment: We really need to see an [mcve] edited into the question.